# iPhone UISwitch start/stop NSTimer help !

Tags: iphone, nstimer, uiswitch

I want to start/stop timer(in main class) with switch(from menu class ),based in my code the timer start fire when switch is ON and doesn't stop when i turn switch OFF. Here is my code :

menu.h

```
@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController  {
id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
IBOutlet UISwitch *fireSwitch;
}
@property (assign)UISwitch* fireSwitch;
-(IBAction)autoFire;
```

menu.m

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "mainViewController.h"
@synthesize fireSwitch;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//[super viewDidLoad];
fireSwitch.on = [defs boolForKey:activateautoplay];

}

-(IBAction)autoFire {
          NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defs setBool:fireSwitch.on forKey:activateautoplay];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Main.h

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#define activateautoplay @"isactivateautoplay"
@interface mainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
NSTimer *Autotimer;
}
-(void)updateImagePosition:(NSTimer*)mytimer;
```

Main.m

```
#import "mainViewController.h"
@sunthesize Autotimer;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defs boolForKey:activateautoplay]) {
    self.Autotimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateImagePosition:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
} else {
    [self.Autotimer invalidate];
}
}


-(void)updateImagePosition:(NSTimer*)mytimer {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind introducing coupling between the two classes, you could always just give FlipsideViewController a reference to mainViewController and have it poke a method directly. Or you could have FlipsideViewController send an appropriate message to its delegate when the value is changed, which could then poke mainViewController.

But the best way from a standpoint of avoiding unnecessary coupling is to have mainViewController listen for `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`, which will automatically be sent when `setBool:forKey:` is called.

---

*Requested edit:*

In Main.m, add a method like this:

```
- (void)startOrStopTimer {
    NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defs boolForKey:activateautoplay]) {
        if (!self.Autotimer) self.Autotimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateImagePosition:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    } else {
        [self.Autotimer invalidate];
        self.Autotimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Then change your `awakeFromNib` to something like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self startOrStopTimer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(startOrStopTimer) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

And be sure to add this to `dealloc`:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

No changes are necessary to FlipsideViewController, and no settings bundle is needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. To use NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification i'm switch to AppSettings (Settings.bundle) ? I don't want to use this. Can you give an example how to use NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification based on my actual code ? Thank you.